# Pointer to a Vector of Vectors in a Function Gives 'expression must have pointer type' error

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, stdvector

Visual Studio Code gives me an 'expression must have pointer type' error for the line `int size = graph->at(node)->size();`. I am aware that I could use [references](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-vector-function-cpp/) but I want to know how to do it with a pointer.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void getPathEdges(vector<vector<int>>* graph, int sink, int count, int node, vector<int>* path) {
    if (node == sink) {
        path->push_back(count);
    }
    else {
        count++;
        int size = graph->at(node)->size();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            getPathEdges(graph, sink, count, i, path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You already mentioned it in the question, but I just want to echo your acknowledgement of references. Raw pointers are good to know about, but once you start writing anything of any magnitude, you'll want to think in terms of smart pointers and references, only dropping to raw pointers to interface with old libraries or when you have no other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want

```
graph->at(node).size();
```

The first access is a `->` because you have a `vector<vector<int>>*` (a pointer). `graph->at(node)` returns a `vector<int>` (*not* a pointer), so access on it is done simply via `.`, not `->`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what your pointer actually points to. If we take away the `*` from the `vector<vector<int>>* graph` declaration, then we are left with this: a vector of vectors.

So, when you have dereferenced the pointer **once** (in `graph->at()`), then you are left with just a vector (not a *pointer* to the vector). (The `->` dereferences the pointer and the `at()` call returns the relevant inner vector.)

So, just replace the second `->` in that line with a simple `.` operator:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void getPathEdges(vector<vector<int>>* graph, int sink, int count, int node, vector<int>* path)
{
    if (node == sink) {
        path->push_back(count);
    }
    else {
        count++;
        int size = graph->at(node).size(); // Only dereference ONCE!
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            getPathEdges(graph, sink, count, i, path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `graph->at(node)` didn't return a pointer, so using `->size()` on it was invalid. Change `int size = graph->at(node)->size();` to `int size = graph->at(node).size();`.